# <Input type="number"> com máscara de horas

Tags: javascript, html5

Como fazer um `<input type="number">` com máscara no formato de horas, que aceite **00:00**.

Se colocar `type="text"` basta utilizar uma máscara, mas e com o `type="number"`?

Comment: Outra alternativa é usar dois `selects` de hora e minuto. Ou um componente como o [Mobiscroll](https://code.google.com/p/mobiscroll/). Não sou fã de máscaras.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este recurso de máscara não é nativo de campo input. Para isso você precisará JavaScript. JQuery por exemplo tem muitos plugins para máscara que voce pode ver [clicando aqui](http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/mask/).

Em especial, recomendo que você tente usar o jquery input mask

Link do projeto: https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask

Nessa página, o autor disponibiliza várias formas de máscara que voce pode usar inclusive de máscara de datas, numericas, monetárias e vários outros formatos disponíveis.

Comment: Obrigado Marcelo!